# Using a glob expression passed as a bash script argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell

#### TL;DR:

Why isn't invoking `./myscript foo*` when `myscript` has `var=$1` the same as invoking `./myscript` with `var=foo*` hardcoded?

---

#### Longer form

I've come across a weird issue in a bash script I'm writing. I am sure there is a simple explanation, but I can't figure it out.

I am trying to pass a command line argument to be assigned as a variable in the script.

I want the script to allow 2 command line arguments as follows:

```
$ bash my_bash_script.bash args1 args2
```

In my script, I assigned variables like this:

```
ARGS1=$1
ARGS2=$2
```

Args 1 is a string descriptor to add to the output file.

Args 2 is a group of directories: "dir1, dir2, dir3", which I am passing as `dir*`

When I assign `dir*` to ARGS2 in the script it works fine, but when I pass `dir*` as the second command line argument, it only includes `dir1` in the wildcard expansion of `dir*`.

I assume this has something to do with how the shell handles wildcards (even when passed as args), but I don't really understand it.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

#### Environment / Usage

I have a group of directories:

```
dir_1_y_map, dir_1_x_map, dir_2_y_map, dir_2_x_map,
    ... dir_10_y_map, dir_10_x_map...
```

Inside these directories I am trying to access a file with extension `".status"` via `*.status`, and `".report.txt"` via `*report.txt`.

I want to pass `dir_*_map` as the second argument to the script and store it in the variable ARGS2, then use it to search within each of the directories for the `".status"` and `".report"` files.

The issue is that passing `dir_*_map` from the command line doesn't give the list of directories, but rather just the first item in the list.  If I assign the variable `ARGS2=dir_*_map` within the script, it works as I intend.

---

#### Workaround: Quoting

It turns out that passing the second argument in quotes allowed the wildcard expansion to work appropriately for `"dir_*_map"`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ARGS1=$1    
ARGS2=$2

touch $ARGS1".extension"

for i in /$ARGS2/*.status
do
    grep -e "string" $i >> $ARGS1".extension"
done
```

Here is an example invocation of the script:

```
sh ~/path/to/script descriptor "dir_*_map"
```

I don't fully understand when/why some arguments must be passed in quotes, but I assume it has to do with the wildcard expansion in the for loop.

Comment: Use a first line in your script as `#!/bin/bash`, rather than calling `bash myscript arg1 ...`. May not fix your problem, but not good practice. Good luck.

Comment: And you really need to give us the smallest sample program (set) that illustrates your problem. You probably only need to be using `"$ARG1"` and `$ARG2` to fix your issue, but without real evidence of what is going on, we have to speculate, eh? ;-) Please edit you Q, rather than create a chain of msgs in comments. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I edited in an example of my code.

Comment: Good show, glad you  updated your Q. Now we can help. BUT your `for i in /$ARGS2/*.status` **;do** when `ARGS2=dir1, dir2, dir3` may work with `for i in /{$ARGS2}/*.status`  And you'll need to remove spaces like `dir1,dir2,dir3`. Will be noodling with this, you try it too. Good luck.

Comment: Learn to run code thru `http://shellcheck.net`, you would find that you're missing `;do` on for `for` line AND that the `i` in `for i` is never used in your block of code. Where do you want to use that `grep $arg1 $i/....` ? I'm guessing?

Comment: wow you're totally right.  I tried to produce an example too quickly.  I've never used shellcheck.net, I will take a look.  I have updated my code with the missing parts.  I am trying your answer as we speak. Thanks!

Comment: Rather than editing "SOLVED!" into the answer, the correct way to indicate that a question is solved is clicking the checkbox to accept an answer; this modifies formatting &c. to indicate that a question is answered, with no edits needed.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I already marked the answer solved, but @shellter asked me to include an invocation example, so I added that.  I will leave off the "SOLVED" part and leave the invocation.  While I have your attention, is it more appropriate to add edits to the bottom of a post or to the top?  Thanks

Comment: It's typical to try to build edits in such a way that the post reads as a coherent unit, rather than setting them off to the top or bottom; edit history is available for anyone who cares whether content is original or new.

Comment: Okay, will keep that in mind for next time.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: BTW, the reason you need to use quotes to delay globbing is that otherwise, each glob expansion becomes a separate argument (so the first result goes in `$2`, the second in `$3`, etc).

Comment: That said, the usual approach would be to `shift` away the first argument, and then iterate over subsequent ones (to get them from `$2`, `$3`, and so on). That is: `arg1=$1; shift; for i; do grep -e "string" "$i" ; done >"${arg1}.extension`

Comment: ...note also that I'm putting the redirection on the *outside* of the loop above; that's more efficient than putting it on the inside, which opens the file every time you want to write to it and closes it again afterwards.

Comment: Great info.  This will help quite a bit down the line.  I've got to run, but I'm going to come back and study the example you gave a bit later tonight.

Comment: I think this has actually expanded beyond the range of comments -- I'll try adding my own answer.

Comment: As an aside -- don't use `sh` to run bash scripts. `sh` is a different interpreter than `bash`, with a much more limited language; if a script starts with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, that's indicating that its author intended it to be run with bash, so use `bash scriptname` if invoking it explicitly.

Comment: BTW, what do you expect `touch file` to do that `>>file` doesn't?

Comment: I was simply writing the script in a rushed manner, and I couldn't remember if `>>file` would create the file or not, so I included `touch file` so I wouldn't have to go back.   I assume, based on your comment, that `>>file` would have been sufficient though?

Comment: Correct. BTW, do you *really* want to append to the file if the script is run more than once, or do you really want to write it from scratch for each invocation (in which case just using `>file` scoped to the loop as a whole rather than to an individual command within that loop would suffice)?

Comment: Yes, I do want to append for this version as I want the output from multiple files to be in a single file at the end. I am sure I could write individual files for each loop and then combine at the end, but wouldn't that be less efficient?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Addressing the "why"

Assignments, as in `var=foo*`, don't expand globs -- that is, when you run `var=foo*`, the literal string `foo*` is put into the variable `foo`, not the list of files matching `foo*`.

By contrast, unquoted use of `foo*` on a command line expands the glob, replacing it with a list of individual names, *each of which is passed as a separate argument*.

Thus, running `./yourscript foo*` doesn't pass `foo*` as `$1` unless no files matching that glob expression exist; instead, it becomes something like `./yourscript foo01 foo02 foo03`, with each argument in a different spot on the command line.

The reason running `./yourscript "foo*"` functions as a workaround is the unquoted expansion inside the script allowing the glob to be expanded at that later time. However, this is bad practice: glob expansion happens concurrent with string-splitting (meaning that relying on this behavior removes your ability to pass filenames containing characters found in `IFS`, typically whitespace), and also means that you can't pass literal filenames when they could also be interpreted as globs (if you have a file named `[1]` and a file named `1`, passing `[1]` would always be replaced with `1`).

---

#### Idiomatic Usage

The idiomatic way to build this would be to `shift` away the first argument, and then iterate over subsequent ones, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
out_base=$1; shift

shopt -s nullglob                 # avoid generating an error if a directory has no .status

for dir; do                       # iterate over directories passed in $2, $3, etc
  for file in "$dir"/*.status; do # iterate over files ending in .status within those
      grep -e "string" "$file"    # match a single file
  done
done >"${out_base}.extension"
```

---

If you have many `.status` files in a single directory, all this can be made more efficient by using `find` to invoke `grep` with as many arguments as possible, rather than calling `grep` individually on a per-file basis:

```
#!/bin/bash
out_base=$1; shift

find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.status' \
  -exec grep -h -- /dev/null '{}' + \
  >"${out_base}.extension"
```

---

Both scripts above expect the globs passed **not** to be quoted on the invoking shell. Thus, usage is of the form:

```
# being unquoted, this expands the glob into a series of separate arguments
your_script descriptor dir_*_map
```

This is considerably better practice than passing globs to your script (which then is required to expand them to retrieve the actual files to use); it works correctly with filenames containing whitespace (which the other practice doesn't), and files whose names are themselves glob expressions.

---

Some other points of note:

- Always put double quotes around expansions! Failing to do so results in the additional steps of string-splitting and glob expansion (in that order) being applied. If you *want* globbing, as in the case of `"$dir"/*.status`, then end the quotes before the glob expression starts.
- `for dir; do` is precisely equivalent to `for dir in "$@"; do`, which iterates over arguments. Don't make the mistake of using `for dir in $*; do` or `for dir in $@; do` instead! These latter invocations combine each element of the list with the first character of `IFS` (which, by default, contains the space, the tab and the newline in that order), then splits the resulting string on any `IFS` characters found within, then expands each component of the resulting list as a glob.
- Passing `/dev/null` as an argument to `grep` is a safety measure: It ensures that you don't have different behavior between the single-argument and multi-argument cases (as an example, `grep` defaults to printing filenames within output only when passed multiple arguments), and ensures that you can't have `grep` hang trying to read from stdin if it's passed no additional filenames at all (which `find` won't do here, but `xargs` can).
- Using lower-case names for your own variables (as opposed to system- and shell-provided variables, which have all-uppercase names) is in accordance with POSIX-specified convention; see fourth paragraph of [the POSIX specification regarding environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html), keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: Wow, this is great, thanks Charles!  I am not a classically trained programmer/computer scientist, so I often approach problems in an inefficient or downright improper way without knowing it.  For instance, I recently read somewhere that it was recommended to use all-uppercase names for variables (for ease of recognition), but I didn't realize that that was to be limited to system- and shell-provided variables.  Anyway, thanks so much for the detailed response, I learned much more than I was hoping for from this post. Happy New Year.

Comment: Also, I did not know about using `shift` to iterate over arguments, this will be massively helpful for me.  Thanks!

Comment: There's a lot of cargo-cult programming in shell -- people who've learned from (often, bad) examples rather than canonical sources, and then teach what they learned that way. Unfortunate, to say the least.