# How to pass ext glob into bash script from sh and then expand it

Tags: shell, global-variables, glob, extglob

I have script `se.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

files="$1"

shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s extglob
for f in a/path/to/all/files/${files}; do
  echo "file process:${f}"
done
shopt -u nullglob
shopt -u extglob
```

When I run:`./se.sh "a*.txt"`, it will process the correct files in the folder.
When I run `./se.sh "{a,1}*.txt"`, I want process files started with `a*.txt` or `1*.txt`, but it didn't run as I expected.

I have searched for quite a while, see

[bash-loop-over-file](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/),

[using-a-glob-expression-passed-as-a-bash-script-argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521320/using-a-glob-expression-passed-as-a-bash-script-argument),

[how-to-pass-a-globbing-pattern-as-parameter-to-a-function-in-bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317946/how-to-pass-a-globbing-pattern-as-parameter-to-a-function-in-bash)

Comment: `{a,1}` is not an extglob, it is braces expansion. If you want extglob `@(a|1)*.txt` use extglob.

Comment: To expand on KamilCuk's answer, look at the [order of shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) -- brace expansion happens _before_ parameter expansion. You'll need `eval` if you want to expand braces stored in a variable.

Comment: You can also use the standard glob `[a1]*.txt` instead of that particular brace expansion.

Comment: ` [a1]*.txt` is only one char, Is it possible if like this: `[abc|123]*.txt` to match  abc*.txt, or 123*.txt? I tested, it not support.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer. Quick demo of my comment:

```bash
$ ls
config.json  example.tcl  tests.toml
$ files='{e,t}*'
$ echo "$files"
{e,t}*
$ declare -a x=( "$files" )
$ declare -p x
declare -a x=([0]="{e,t}*")
$ eval declare -a x=( "$files" )
$ declare -p x
declare -a x=([0]="example.tcl" [1]="tests.toml")
```

Of course, you don't want to blindly `eval` any user input without thorough validation.